# How could create a table from selected data with C3.js

Tags: c3.js

I have created a chart with a subchart with the C3.js library. I used:

```
subchart:{    
  show:true
  onbrush: function (domain) {                                                          
   test = chart.internal.filterByXDomain(chart.data(),domain);                              
  },
}
```

How can I generate a dinamic table with the values into the object "test"?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the HTML and set it to one of the elements

```
...
onbrush: function (domain) {
    var test = chart.internal.filterByXDomain(chart.data(), domain);

    var table = '<table><tr><th>x</th><th>y</th></tr>';
    test[0].values.forEach(function(e) {
        table += '<tr><td>' + e.x + '</td><td>' + e.value + '</td></tr>'
    })
    table += '</table>';

    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = table;
}
```

where you have a an element with ID range

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e3esfsd6/